# Statically importing Kotlin Companion methods?

Tags: kotlin

tl:dr; Is it possible to `import` a method inside a companion object of another class, **without** qualifying the import with `Companion`? That is, is there any possible way I can say `import Bar.toFoo` instead of `import Bar.Companion.toFoo`, assuming `toFoo` is a method on `Bar`'s companion object?

---

We're migrating a class from Java to Kotlin. Our class looks like this:

```
class Bar {
  static Foo toFoo() {
    return new Foo();
  }
}
```

And then, to use it, from a class that happens to be Kotlin, we say something like:

```
import Bar.toFoo;

// ...
    Bar().convert(toFoo()); // like a Java 8 Collector
// ...
```

When we convert `Bar` to Kotlin, it looks like this:

```
class Bar {
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic fun toFoo() = Foo()
  }
}
```

We'd like the calling code to work without modification, however

```
import Bar.toFoo
```

no longer works, even with @JvmStatic! Instead, we **have** to update it to

```
import Bar.Companion.toFoo
```

which we'd rather not have to do -- we want to switch the Bar class to Kotlin without updating the callers.

Thoughts? We're using Kotlin 1.1.2-2.

Comment: I couldn't get the reason why you try to use `Bar().convert(toFoo())` instead of `Bar().toFoo()`. Why does it have to be static?

Comment: Well, because `toFoo()` actually *is* a Java 8 Collector class, like `Collectors.toList()` or `Collectors.toSet()`, and is modeled the same way.

Comment: Something like `import static example.Bar.toFoo;` should work (changed package from your example because Java cannot have classes in the root package) - what compiler error are you seeing? And is it in the IDE or in the build?

Comment: Um, Java *can* have classes in the root package, and Kotlin doesn't have an `import static` statement. The error I'm seeing is `unresolved reference`.

Comment: Sorry, to be specific with Java: `It is a compile time error to import a type from the unnamed package.` But it sounds like I misunderstood the question anyway, because it sounds like you are trying to import the companion object function into another Kotlin class.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike Java, Kotlin does not allow you to call static members via instance reference. Java dispatches these members based on the compile time declaration, so in

```
class Bar {
    static Foo toFoo() { return new Foo(); }
}

class Foo extends Bar {
    static Foo toFoo() { return new Foo(); }
}

class Baz {
    void test() {
        Bar fooAsBar = new Foo();
        Foo foo = fooAsBar.toFoo();
    }
}
```

In Java, `fooAsBar.toFoo()` will actually call `Bar.toFoo()` (the declared type) and not `Foo.toFoo()` (the runtime type). This is a source of misunderstanding and not good programming practice, so Kotlin does not support it.

However, you can define an extension function on Bar:

```
fun Bar?.toFoo() = Bar.toFoo()
```

Then you can call

```
val foo = fooAsBar.toFoo()
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question